Como armazenar os valores de dois vetores em um terceiro vetor?
Estou fazendo um código no visualg, na qual os valores de dois vetores e suas posições devem ser armazenadas em um terceiro vetor, mas eu não sei como fazer. Gostaria que alguém me explicasse.
Inicio
   para i de 1 ate 3 passo 1 faca
      escreval ("Dgite um número para vA:")
      leia (vA[i])
      escreval ("Digite um número para vB:")
      leia (vB[i])
   fimpara
   para i de 1 ate 3 passo 1 faca
      vC[i] <- vA[i]*2
   fimpara
   para i de 4 ate 6 passo 4 faca
      vC[i] <- vB[i]*2
   fimpara
   escreval ("Os valores são:" , vC[i])
Fimalgoritmo


Esta pergunta já foi postada e lá já foram fornecidas as orientações relevantes. Desta forma, o espaço de comentários foi desativado aqui para evitar descentralização de informações (mas continua disponível na postagem original, se restaurada).
